# Error on setting reference CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

Im using the code bellow. Everything is OK until I want to set the reference of the customer (account), on the workReportItem in the last line of "var workReportItem". The code is:

```cs
private static void AddWRItoServiceActivity(IOrganizationService service, Guid id)
    {
        using (var crm = new XrmServiceContext(service))
        {

            var serviceactivity = crm.ServiceAppointmentSet.Where(c => c.Id == id).First();
            var serviceitem = crm.brd_serviceitemSet.Where( c => c.brd_RegardingServiceId.Id == serviceactivity.ServiceId.Id);

            foreach (var S in serviceitem)
            {
                var workReportItem = new brd_workreportitem
                   {
                       brd_name = S.brd_name,
                       brd_serviceappointment_brd_workreportitem = serviceactivity,
                       brd_brd_serviceitem_brd_workreportitem_ServiceItem = S,
                       brd_brd_servicereportitem_brd_workreportitem_ServiceReportItem = S.brd_brd_servicereportitem_brd_serviceitem_ServiceReportItem,
                       brd_Customer = serviceactivity.Customers.First().ToEntityReference(),
                    };

                // Setting the optionset value "type"
                OptionSetValue myOptionSet = new OptionSetValue();
                myOptionSet.Value = S.brd_brd_servicereportitem_brd_serviceitem_ServiceReportItem.brd_Type.Value;
                workReportItem.Attributes["brd_type"] = myOptionSet;

                crm.AddObject(workReportItem);
                crm.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is: Value can not be null. Parameter name: source.
It is appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: I've tested the plugin without setting account on it and it worked well.

Comment: What is the value of `S.brd_brd_servicereportitem_brd_serviceitem_ServiceReportItem.brd_Type.Value`?

Comment: It is the value of the option set on the servicereportitem entity.

Comment: I more meant, when you attach the debugger and inspect the property, what value does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used below code to set reference on a party list:

```cs
ActivityParty activityParty = new ActivityParty { PartyId = new EntityReference(MissionAccount.LogicalName, MissionAccount.Id) };
var customer = new List<ActivityParty>();
customer.Add(activityParty);
serviceactivity.Customers = customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks likes Customers is null.  You'll have to perform another query on the customers set in order to pull back the customers for the service activity.